# ROS fuerte swig-wx

Tags: macos, ros-fuerte, macos-lion, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

still trying to install ROS fuerte in OSX lion this formula seems to be broken, I tried brew install -vd swig-wx
long story short :

```
Error: #<BuildError: Failed executing: make install >
```

/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:504:in `system' /usr/local/Library/Formula/swig-wx.rb:15:in` install'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/build.rb:118:in `install' /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:221:in` brew'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:533:in `stage' /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/extend/fileutils.rb:21:in` mktemp'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:529:in `stage' /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:216:in` brew'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/build.rb:98:in `install' /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/build.rb:42:in` main'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/build.rb:12
/usr/local/Library/Formula/swig-wx.rb:12
==> Rescuing build...
When you exit this shell Homebrew will attempt to finalise the installation.
If nothing is installed or the shell exits with a non-zero error code,
Homebrew will abort. The installation prefix is:
/usr/local/Cellar/swig-wx/1.3.29

how will this affect ROS fuerte? Is there a known solution?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42690/ros-fuerte-swig-wx/) by [ee05073](https://answers.ros.org/users/2918/ee05073/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2012-08-30

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ee05073](https://answers.ros.org/users/2918/ee05073/) on 2012-08-31**:
I found "To install the swig-wx I followed this post http://ardadv.blogspot.com.au/2012/05/using-ros-robot-operating-system-fuerte.html >> cd /Library/Caches/Homebrew/swigwx--git ./configure make make install
Paul Flick (Jul 12 '12)" to be the best answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This commit fixes this problem for me on Lion:

https://github.com/ros/homebrew-fuerte/commit/9bb9228b210ad0feb76ef778bf44886a74b80d44

That is, `brew update` and then `brew install swig-wx` should now work.

---

Originally posted by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) with karma: 1626 on 2012-09-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check that swig-wx is installed correctly. See [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/36890/unable-to-find-swigswg-and-unable-to-find-pythonswg/) for details. Might be the problem you're facing

---

Originally posted by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) with karma: 1834 on 2012-08-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1